# Função que executa em tempo agendado

Tags: node.js

Como criar uma função que seja executada por exemplo a cada 5 minutos no nodejs.

Encontrei a lib: http://bunkat.github.io/later porém não sei como faço para ela ser executada sempre, e nao só uma vez

Comment: Talvez possa ser o que queira; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868590/setting-a-timer-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso a lib [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) e tem funcionado muito bem.

Mas você também pode fazer isto com JavaScript puro, basta usar a função [setInternal](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args).

```
setInterval(function () { 
  console.log('Isto aqui vai ser executado a cada 5 minutos'); 
}, 5 * 60 * 1000); //300.000, o que corresponde a 5 minutos
```